# Using jQuery ajax() to POST to a Tastypie resource results in a 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, tastypie

I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Everything works in Postman, so I know the API is fine. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with the ajax.

I'm getting teh following error with the code below: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/feedback/api/fb/feedback/ 404 (NOT FOUND)`

```
$('#feedback-send').click(function(event) {
    var feedback_api = "/feedback/api/fb/feedback/";
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "user": $("input[name=user]").val(),
        "feedback": $("input[name=feedback]").val(),
        "page": $("input[name=page]").val(),
        "user_agent": $("input[name=user_agent]").val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: feedback_api,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('got it');
            console.log(data);
            //$('.alert.information').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            //$('#feedback-form').fadeOut();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.alert.error').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Could you debug with `curl`? Otherwise 404 means the URL is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how the content was being sent. The data key values were wrong.